# Use the Well Ordering Principle to prove that every finite, nonempty set of real numbers has a minimum element.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is a textbook problem.

Here's my proof

Proof: By W.O.P
let C be a set that contains real numbers and doesn't contain any minimum number.
Assume C to be Non Empty for purpose of contradiction.$-(a)$

Assume  m $\in$ C, be the smallest number that belong in C.    $-(b)$

Therefore there exists following 2 cases:
(Since C doesn't have any smallest number.)

$i)$other number smaller than m exists in C.
Since from $(b)$ m is the smallest number that $\in$ C. Thus this case is False.
$ii)$there exists other element as m.
As per the definition of sets a set contains only non duplicate value.Thus this case is also false

Since the result of above cases result in False.we can conclude that our assumption ($a$) is proven false since assumption ($b$) is proven true from above results.
Thus there exists no non empty set which doesn't contain a minimum element.

I believe that the problem is wrongly proved but having proved it myself i am having trouble in finding the mistake.
Help me find the mistake which i have committed in this proof.

PS. (by cases I mean the cases required to prove C to be finite and not containing a minimum number or cases to prove assumption b false)

Comment: I do not understand (b).  What might be a contradictory case if $C$ doesn't contain any minimum number? What would it contradict? What happens to your proof if somebody suggests the strictly positive real numbers with the usual ordering?

Comment: Nor am I clear whether you are looking at the [Well Ordering Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) or the [Well Ordering Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem)

Comment: I have made changes to the question please check.

Comment: As instructed in the Textbook I was solving the question by Well Ordering Principle. I myself solved this proof, and when went to search for the solution online found the question to be solved by a different approach.

Comment: After checking solution to the problem online, I now believe that i have proved the question wrongly and i am not able to find my  mistake in my approach to the question

Comment: With the Well Ordering Principle, you want to concentrate on the set being finite.  Clearly a set with one element has a minimum element.  So consider non-empty finite sets with no minimum value: if there are any then there would be a smallest, by the Well Ordering Principle on the natural numbers; consider any smallest such set and any two of its elements, one of which is larger than the other; if you remove the larger of the two you have a smaller set, which must have a minimum element which will also be a minimum of the larger set - so the set of non-empty finite sets must be empty

Comment: Thanks @Henry, I now have understood the solution and the part where my proof went wrong.

Comment: @Henry i have made changes to the proof can you please check and ascertain whether this time it's done correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the same assumption you made  " there is no minimum element in $C$ " . But , because of well ordered property in $C$ ,every element is comparable in your non empty subset $C$ .

so take any two arbitrary element from $C$ and then they must be comparable. But because of finiteness property of $C$ , you will find this process should end at a particular point.  That will be contradiction